Returning an image in a function
I am writing a function that takes in an image, modifies it, and returns the modified image.
Image SomeFunction(Image img)
{
   Image modified = img
   
   // modify the clone

   return modified
}

Now in the main code block, setting an image variable to be the returned clone throws off an error: "Unable to determine the physical size of this image expression". Passing an image is obviously not like in another language, say Python. Could someone please help?

In DM script, it is important to distinguish between and understand the two ways to do image assignment, via = or :=. Unfortunately, this is not covered very coherently in the on-line documentation (being only very briefly and tangentially covered in the "Types and Variables" and "Expressions" sections), so this is a common conundrum for those who are new to DM scripting.
The key thing to realize is that := is really the only way to assign an Image object to an Image variable, like this:
Image targeting := GetFrontImage();

So this is probably what you are intending to do in your code.
The simple = sign is only for pixel-by-pixel operations, so-called "image expressions". These are actually very powerful and the fastest way to change image pixel values in systematic ways via mathematical expressions (much, much faster and more efficient than using GetPixel() and SetPixel(), avoid these as much as possible). However, when doing such pixel-by-pixel assignments, it is important that images on both sides of the = sign have exactly the same dimensions and sizes.
In fact, the simpler, faster, and more typical way to implement the sort of function you show in your example would be to truly clone the input image object and then modify its pixel values via an image expression, as follows:
Image ModifyImage(Image inputImg)
{
    Image modifiedImg := inputImg.ImageClone();
    modifiedImg = [a mathematical image expression];

    return modifiedImg;
}


Mike's post is correct, but I would like to amend it with a bit of additional information:
For images, = is a copy value operation. The values are computed on the right-hand-side and copied (potentially type-cast) to the left on a pixel-by-pixel basis. Left and Right side need to be of same size (i.e. same number of dimensions and same dimension sizes.)
For images, := is a assign operation. The image/expression on the right-hand sides is assigned to left-hand-side (which needs to be an image variable).
Some examples:

image img := GetFrontImage()Get the front-most displayed image and assign it to variable img. i.e. img is this image now. Changing img will change the displayed image.
image img = GetFrontImage() Get the front-most displayed image and copy its values into a new image that is assigned to the variable img. Changing img will not change the displayed image. The image img will always be a real-4 image with no calibrations and other meta-info (tags), regardless of what the front-most displayed image has as number format.
image img = IntegerImage("Test",4,1,128,128)  img is a real-4 image here. The code creates an Integer image in memory, then creates a new (by default real-4 image) and copied over the integer values. A vert common mistake.


Another thing worth knowing is, that images passed as function/method parameters are always passed by reference not by value. Hence the following code will modify the image and the ImageClone() in Mike's answer prevents modification of the input image.
void ModifyImage(image in)
{
    in = iradius
}


image img:=Realimage("Test",4,128,128)
img = icol
showimage(img)
OKDialog("Now Modify")
ModifyImage(img)

The same is true for all other "object" like parameters ( imageDocument,TagGroup, ImageDisplay, ROI, Component, etc.).
But "simple" number and string parameters  are different. They are by default are passed as values (i.e. copies) unless explicitly passed as reference:
void CantModify(string str, number num)
{
    num = 3
    str = "new"
}

void Modify(string &str, number &num)
{
    num = 3
    str = "new"
}

string inputStr = "Test"
number inputNum = 10

result("\n Before: " + inputStr + " | " + inputNum )
CantModify(inputStr,inputNum)
result("\n After : " + inputStr + " | " + inputNum )
Modify(inputStr,inputNum)
result("\n After : " + inputStr + " | " + inputNum )

